# Xamarin iOS - Push Notifications - Distinguish push notification clicked from arrived

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm creating a Xamarin.iOS application that includes push notifications.

I've noticed that if the app is not running (not just at the background), when a push notification arrived (with the correct payload), the OS will take over handling the notification and will present it to the user and if the user clicks on the notification while it closed, I will be able to get this information from the NSDictionary options parameter of the FinishedLaunching method (finding if it contains the UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey key)

so far, everything is great.

but I have two scenarios,

1) the push notification arrives when the application is running.
2) the user clicked on a push notification that arrived earlier (while the app was closed) after he launches the app

for both scenarios, the method ReceivedRemoteNotification is invoked.

but for each scenario I want to do a different business logic, my question is:
How do I know if the ReceivedRemoteNotification was invoked by scenario 1 or scenario 2?

I've new to Xamarin and I've searched the web for it, but couldn't find a solution.

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I've seen ReceivedRemoteNotification called when the app is started via user tap on a notification received while the app is running. I've only seen this called if the app is running when the notification is delivered at the device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check the application state using the following condition, inside didReceiveRemoteNotification method,

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground || state == UIApplicationStateInactive)
{//write here...Application opened by tapping notification}
```

FYI- The above code is in Objective-c

Comment: Compared to my answer, this definitely looks worth a try!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think I've seen `ReceivedRemoteNotification` called when the app is started via user tap on a notification received while the app is stopped. I've only seen this called if the app is running when the notification is delivered at the device. So we distinguish by passing a flag named `isAppAlreadyRunning` set `false` if called from `FinishedLaunching`, `true` if called from `ReceivedRemoteNotification`.

This seems to be working well in a shipping Xamarin.iOS app. All code is in `AppDelegate.cs`:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{

...

    // Initialize Xamarin Forms and load the application.
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new Forms.App(0));

    // Check if App was opened by Push Notification.
    var keyName = new NSString("UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey");
    if (options != null && options.Keys != null && options.Keys.Length != 0 && options.ContainsKey(keyName))
    {
        NSDictionary pushOptions = options.ObjectForKey(keyName) as NSDictionary;
        ProcessPushNotification(pushOptions, false);
    }

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}

public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication app, NSDictionary userInfo)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ReceivedRemoteNotification entered.");
    ProcessPushNotification(userInfo, true);
}

protected void ProcessPushNotification(NSDictionary userInfo, bool isAppAlreadyRunning)
{
    if (userInfo == null) return;
    if (isAppAlreadyRunning)
    { 
        // do something with this knowledge...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try the approach proposed by @RJV Kumar as tweaked by OP, because it looks a lot more iOS-aware. Nice!

Comment: this solution is actually still helpful, this solution will work in the case where the app is not running on the device, the accepted answer it'll only work when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you very much @RJVKumar this is what I was looking for !

To help others this is the code in C#:

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
{
    if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
    {
    }
    else if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Background)
    {
    }
    else if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive)
    {
    }
}
```